# Loader image is not loading in chrome, while calling an API

Tags: web-services, api, google-chrome, browser, dojo

I have the issue in chrome browser.

Loader image or text not loading, while API calls.

Chrome delays other actions while calling API and down into stuckness.

My code structure is

```
Placed a span with loader background, 

<span id='logging' class='hide'></span>

Click on 'Login' Button, 
{ 
  dojo.query('#logging').removeClass('hide'); // Show the loader 
  <API Call Script here.>
  dojo.query('#logging').addClass('hide'); // Hide the loader 
}
```

It has been working in browser IE, Firefox .. etc, but not in chrome browser

**Can anyone help?**

Thank You.

Comment: whats a 'stuckness' ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you extended the query correctly with the functionality youre using? dojo.query is loaded differently in regards to whether or not the native selector-engine is 'sufficient'..

Try adding (1.7+ only) a require to dojo/NodeList-dom around the query calls

```
require(["dojo/query", "dojo/NodeList-dom"], function(dj_query){ 
  dj_query('#logging').removeClass('hide'); // Show the loader 
  <API Call Script here.>
  dj_query('#logging').addClass('hide'); // Hide the loader 
});
```